# TypeORM save incorrectly attempts to insert instead of update

Tags: typeorm

I have a strange issue with TypeORM. For this entity:

```
@Entity({name:"registered_items"})
export class RegisteredItem {

    @PrimaryColumn({name: 'itemid', type: 'bigint'})
    itemId?: number;

    @Column({name: 'somestring', length: 15, nullable: true})
    someString?: string;

    //.. more strings

    @Column({name: 'registertimestamp', nullable: true})
    registerTimestamp?: Date;    

    @Column({name: 'isenabled'})
    isEnabled?: boolean;
    
    //..more booleans
}
```

TypeORM fails to detect that a row already exists with that `itemId` and  attempts to do an insert, instead of an update,

whereas with this, simpler entity:

```
@Entity({name:"something_simple"})
export class SomethingSimple {

    @PrimaryColumn({name: 'thingid', length: 32})
    thingId?: string;

    @Column({name: 'something', nullable: true, type: "smallint"})
    something?: number;

    @CreateDateColumn({name: 'inserttimestamp'})
    inserttimestamp?: Date;
}
```

it functions as expected, doing an insert when the item doesn't exist and update when it does. Why does it fail to function expectedly with the first entity?
The code in both cases is equivalent:

```
getRepository(RegisteredItem).save(item)
//and:
getRepository(SomethingSimple).save(s)
```

I can see in the debug log that it correctly performs SELECT before determining which action to take, but does not make the correct conclusion from the SELECT result.
When I do this manually (instead of `getRepository(..).save()..` ):

```
const exists = await getRepository(RegisteredItem).hasId(item);
if(exists) {
    return getRepository(RegisteredItem).update({itemId: item.itemId}, item);
}
else {
    return getRepository(RegisteredItem).insert(item);
}
```

the correct branch is selected.

When attempting to pre-load the entity with `await getRepository(RegisteredItem).findOne({itemId: <something>})` and attempting to save that, then that also fails because of the primary key violation.

Therefore how come the getRepository.save() doesn't work for one entity? The DB used is PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

had similar or very similar case, was receiving constant duplicate entity error on primary key. For me it helped to change type of primary key from BIGINT to INT.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until i did **findone** then **.save**,
1st get the data to update using  *data= this.userRepository.findOne(id)* then you can apply **userRepository.save(data)** to this data.
this is my source code try to do the same :

```
const userUpdated = await this.userRepository.findOne(id)
      let dataUpdated = {
        ...userUpdated,
        username: data.payload.username,
        firstname: data.payload.firstname,
        lastname: data.payload.lastname,
        email: data.payload.email,
        company: data.payload.selectedCompany,
        roles: data.payload.selectedRoles
      }

      const user = await this.userRepository.save(dataUpdated);
```

Comment: I tried that approach but it didn't work for me for some strange reason.

Comment: Please tell me are you working with many to many or not ? just a simple crud so i can share with you what i did in both cases because i had this problem but now i fixed it

Comment: No relations between entities at all in this case.

Comment: try this : 
await this.roleRepository.update(id, { ...data.payload });
const role = await this.roleRepository.find({ id });
      return {
        role,
        success: true,
      };

Comment: What should the result of that be? If it comes to that then I might as well do the exists check explicitly. My concern is why the implicit SELECT done by TypeORM fails to detect the existence of one type of entity but succeeds for another.